# Npm install on GitHub Pull Request fails for the package referenced from a public GitHub repository

Tags: github, npm, ssh, permission-denied, public-key

In the `package.json` file, I have added a dependency that is referencing one of our public repositories. The dependency in the `package.json` looks like below:

```
    "ffprobe-static": "git+https://github.com/company-name/repo-name.git",
```

I can successfully run `npm install` locally and use this dependency, but when I push this code, our GitHub workflows where we execute `npm install` fails with the below error:

```
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'x.x.x.x' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I don't understand the reason for this error, since the repository we are referencing is public, and also I can access the same repository when I install dependencies locally.

Note that the repository that is running this code is a private repository, but the referenced repository is public, but under the same organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a config to force https URLs, at least for testing, in your GitHub workflow:

```yaml
- name: Fix URL access
      run: echo -e '[url "https://github.com/"]\n  insteadOf = "ssh://git@github.com/"' >> ~/.gitconfig
    - name: Checkout server
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      ...
```

Or (as [in here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116#issuecomment-583790750), just to illustrate where you can put the `git config insteadOf` command):

```yaml
on: push
jobs:
  check-elm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Checkout submodules
      shell: bash
      run: |
        # From https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116#issuecomment-583221947
        git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf
          ssh://git@github.com/
        git submodule sync --recursive
        git -c "http.extraheader=Authorization: basic ${{secrets.GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}}" -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --recursive --depth=1
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '8.16.0'
    - run: npm run test
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by adding the below step after checkout in the YAML file. Also, set the `persist-credentials` option to false in the checkout step.

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Reconfigure git to use HTTP authentication
        run: >
          git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf
          ssh://git@github.com/
```

Comment: I tried the script in your comment but that didn't fix the issue. I think the syntax was just a little different. But the script in my answer did the trick. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes: `ssh://git@github.com/` instead of `git@github.com:`. I have edited my answer to reflect the SSH URL you are using.

Comment: Ok. Gave you the check mark.